# node.js how to get external remote IP address of a web server - some page stackoverflow.com for example?

Tags: node.js, ip

by request.ip I can get IP of an client. But how to get external remote IP address of a web server - some page stackoverflow.com for example? Headers don't give me IP. On chrome developer tool - NETWORK tab I can see in 
**general** HEADERS that it has:

*Request URL:*

*Request Method:*

*Status Code:200*

**AND**
*Remote Address:**67.138.5.12:80***

but as I said, I can't dig to it when I request headers. There must be other way since chrome got this. Maybe some dns calculation by dns page name (page name = this IP)?

Comment: Googling "node.js dns" looks plenty promising. https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz! Another hour of harassing the google saved. BTW: you can answer this question and I will mark it as accepted answer and delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @ceejayoz says:

```
const dns = require('dns');

dns.lookup('nodejs.org', (err, addresses, family) => {
  console.log('addresses:', addresses);
});
```

// this will print out nodejs.org IP